# How to avoid "overfull" warnings with tcblistings and parskip package?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, parskip

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%%% this two following packages are used in the format I have to use
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}
     checking content
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

it compiles well, with correctly aligned boxes, but it gives a

```
mwe-tcbox.tex|12 warning| Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
```

I tried the  `tcbset` trick adapted [from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187339/overfull-hbox-when-using-tcolorbox-with-parskip-half-koma-option), but it does not work; the line

```
\tcbset{before app=\parfillskip0pt}
```

(adding `[hooks]` to the `tcolorbox` package) is silent, but does not solve the warning.

If I remove the `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` from the code all is well --- but I really can't do that, because it is in the format I have to use for this document. I can hack it with something like `width=0.9\linewidth` in the options of the tcolorbox, but well --- It's a hack.

I also could manage to [silence the warnings using the `silence` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273376/38080) --- but again, this will also shut off *real* warnings.

Can I avoid the warning and still using the full textwidth for the color boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parfill` option to the `parskip` package sets `\parfillskip` to `30pt plus 1fil`, in order to avoid the final line of a paragraph to end (almost) flush with the right margin: no wonder you get an overfull line by exactly 30pt.

Redefine the `parskip` style to issue `\parfillskip=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%% this two following packages are used in the format I have to use
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\tcbset{
  parskip/.style={
    before={\par\pagebreak[0]\parindent=0pt},
    after={\parfillskip=0pt\par},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}
     checking content
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]

\the\parfillskip

\end{document}
```

I added `\the\parfillskip` to show it's correctly reset and also the `draft` option to prove there's no overfull box.

[image]

Comment: It works mot of the time (thanks!). I still have the overfull box warning if I use `breakable` and a break occurs into the box...

Comment: ...and the problem is that in the manual it is stated that "The given `/tcb/before` and `/tcb/after` values are used only before the first
and after the last part of the break sequence." --- I was not able to find hooks for the breaks...

Comment: ...so I finally added `\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax` to the preamble. ;-) I am not sure about the aesthetic of the 30pt fixed thing, anyway.

Comment: @Rmano Just remove the `parfill` option, then.

Comment: Yes, that would be the perfect thing. Unfortunately I do not control the class file... so I have to do it after-the-fact. No one will notice ;-)

Comment: @Rmano They will, because you're changing the defaults. `;-)`.

Comment: I will, probably. Most of the readers of these documents are used to typical "Word" typesetting quality, so I doubt that a finesse like a too full last paragraph line will ever be noticed ;-).