# How to suppress warnings

Tags: errors, compiling, warnings

Many other languages posses the ability to suppress diagnostic messages on specific sections of their source code, while still reporting these messages in other sections.

For example, in C++ with gcc one can use `#pragma GCC diagnostic` commands to turn compiler messages on and off, and Java has the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Does LaTeX posses a similar feature or another way to disable diagnostic messages in a specific section of code?

---

As a specific example, I have some code that triggers these warnings:

```
paper.tex:8: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/fontawesometwo/m/it' undefined(Font)
    using `U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 8.
paper.tex:20: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/fontawesometwo/b/n' undefined(Font)
    using `U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 20.
```

How can I turn off this warning, but only for those two specific lines of that specific file?

Note that I am **not** looking for the 'correct' way to fix warnings, I am only looking for a general method to *suppress* warnings.

Comment: have a look at [silence](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/silence/silence-doc.pdf) package...  look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273376/38080 for an example

Comment: You can have a look at [ChkTeX](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/).